# Why is there no activation function in upsampling layer of U-net?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

In the [U-net](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/), have activation functions in all the layers but there seems to be no activation function in the upsampling layer (that is done using transpose convolution). Why does this offer more efficiency than having an activation function?

[image]

From my understanding, activation functions offer non-linearity. So, this question really is, what benefit is there to maintaining linearity in transpose convolutions but maintaining *non*-linearity on regular convolutions. Wouldn't it just always be best to have an activation function in these layers?

My only other intuition is that perhaps, they're trying to keep the upsampling as closely related to regular morphological interpolation methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your interpretation is right: they were just trying to keep the process similar to the upsampling operated with classic interpolations because of a better interpretability of the architecture (while still allowing flexibility to the network, that can still learn the best weights for the upsampling). In general, if you want to add more non-linearity, you can enter any desired activation function (such as a ReLU) after that level, but personally, from my experience, I would say that performance will not change much.

Answer (score 0):

In the original paper (Section 2), there seems to be ReLU activation function in the upsampling path?

"Every step in the expansive path consists of an upsampling of the
feature map followed by a 2x2 convolution (“up-convolution”) that halves the
number of feature channels, a concatenation with the correspondingly cropped
feature map from the contracting path, and two 3x3 convolutions, each followed by a ReLU."

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The assumption made by the OP is incorrect. The upsampling layers in the UNet do involve an activation function. Below is a screenshot from the video on the page linked by the OP that shows the exact upconvolution operation used in UNet. You can see that they use ReLU in this operation.

[image]

Comment: NOTE: while this answers the OP's question, I think there's an unrelated error in the screenshot taken from the UNet authors' video. When taking the dot product between kernel weights w(i, j, k, l) and input values a(x, y, k), the summation is over k only, i.e., there no summation over i and j as shown in the screenshot. The output of the summation is specific to i and j - that's why i and j appear in the subscripts of the LHS b in the equation in the screenshot. See https://d2l.ai/chapter_computer-vision/transposed-conv.html for a more detailed explanation.